# Room Database Android Studio

Tags: android-room

I am developing a player which has to play both audio and video songs. I want to use Room database library to save audio files, video files, folders containing audio files and folders containing video files i.e; I have to create four tables. Shall I define a single Dao interface/abstract class for insert/delete etc functions or define seperate Dao for each table?

Answer (score 0):

> Shall I define a single Dao interface/abstract class for insert/delete etc functions or define seperate Dao for each table?

It doesn't really matter, whichever suits.

> I want to use Room database library to save audio files, video files, folders containing audio files and folders containing video files i.e;

It is possibly not feasible to save these in the database due to the potentially large amount of storage. It is more practical to store the path/url to the actual files.

Comment: I am saving paths/urls to tables, not files. The problem is that some time empty rows are extracted from table when extracting/getting files path/urls into lazycolumn in compose and also the all folders are not shown. With out using room database, no said single problem is observed.